# Fixed size element overlapping sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed width element that needs to be centered when it fits on the page but if not then extend beyond the page width accessible with page scroll. I've got close to making this work but it overlaps the sidebar.

1/ How can I centre the `large-fixed-grid` (green element) if it fits inside the container/screen width but if not start it from after the `sidebar`?

2/ Additionally, if I scroll horizontally to show the fixed width element, the `top-header` shows a gap with difference between screen width and `large-fixed-grid` width (red element). Is there a way to offset the `top-header` inline with the scrolling horizontally so there is no white gap?

The yellow element should still be centred on the original width without scrolling. It currently behaves as expected.

I have tried lots of CSS variations but cannot get this working.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7tg2jo69/

Image:
[image]

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header class="top-header"></header>
<div class="page">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">Item1</div>
  </div>
  
  <main class="main">
    <article class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="small-flexible-grid">
          
          </div>        
          <div class="large-fixed-grid">
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
  
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.top-header {
  height: 40px;
  background:red;
}

.sidebar {
  z-index: -1;
  background:blue;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.content {
  padding: 1.1rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.row { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}


.small-flexible-grid {
  background: yellow;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
}

.large-fixed-grid {
  background: green;
  min-width:600px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**Update:**

I've fixed 1/ by removing class `justify-content-center` entirely and adding `margin: auto;`  to both `.small-flexible-grid` and `.large-fixed-grid`

Answer (score 0):

how about change the styles to

```
.large-fixed-grid { 
  background: green; 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 600px; 
  height: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: The width needs to be fixed. I managed to solve this in the update.

Answer (score 0):

Solved both of these using the following

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9wdzgb1/

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header id="top-header-onscroll" class="top-header"></header>
<div class="page">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">Item1</div>
  </div>
  
  <main class="main">
    <article class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-flexible-grid">
          
          </div>        
          <div class="large-fixed-grid">
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
  
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.top-header {
  height: 40px;
  background:red;
}

.sidebar {
  z-index: -1;
  background:blue;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.content {
  padding: 1.1rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.row { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.small-flexible-grid {
  background: yellow;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.large-fixed-grid {
  background: green;
  min-width:600px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var top_header = document.getElementById('top-header-onscroll');
    if (top_header) {
        if (window.pageXOffset > 0) {
            top_header.style.width = (window.innerWidth + window.pageXOffset - 30) + 'px';
        }
        else {
            top_header.style.width = "";
        }
    }
}
```